# Panel not changing page in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, panels

I'm trying to code a panel that closes and changes the current page after a user taps a link but nothing happens after the links are tapped.

I originally tried to change the page by with a tags (ie. ) to no avail. Here's my code:

```js
$("a").on("tap", function(){
    switch($(this).attr("id")) {
  case "#woke":
   $.mobile.changePage("#woke");
   break;
        case "#network": 
   $.mobile.changePage("#network");
   break;
    }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Organize.me</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 
 <body>     
  <div data-role="page" id="woke">
   <!--Navigation panel with links-->
   <div data-role="panel" data-dismissible="true" data-swipe-close="true" data-display="overlay" data-fixed-position="true" id="menu">
    <div data-role="header">      
      <h1>Menu</h1> 
      <a href="#network" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Back</a>
    </div>    
    <nav><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> 
     <a href="#woke" class="nav-woke"><li class="buttons">Get Woke</li></a>
     <a href="#network"><li class="buttons">My Network</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Find Orgs</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Events</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Voting</li></a>   
    </ul></nav>
   </div>
   
   <!--Header-->
   <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#menu" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left">Menu</a>
    <h1>Get Woke</h1>
   </div>
   
   <!--Content-->
   <div data-role="content"></div>
   
   <!--Footer-->
   <div data-role="footer">&copy;Scripts of Steele</footer>
  </div>
  
  <div data-role="page" id="network">
   <!--Navigation panel with links-->
   <div data-role="panel" data-dismissible="true" data-swipe-close="true" data-display="overlay" data-fixed-position="true" id="menu">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a href="#network" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Back</a>
      <h1>Menu</h1>    
    </div>    
    <nav><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> 
     <a href="#woke" data-rel="open"><li class="buttons">Get Woke</li></a>
     <a href="#network" data-rel="open"><li class="buttons">My Network</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Find Orgs</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Events</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Voting</li></a>   
    </ul></nav>
   </div>
   
   <!--Header-->
   <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#menu" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left">Menu</a>
    <h1>My Networks</h1>
   </div>
   
   <!--Content-->
   <div data-role="content"></div>
   
   <!--Footer-->
   <div data-role="footer">&copy;Scripts of Steele</footer>
  </div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting an `id` but maybe you want to select the `href` (or better, add an id)

```js
$("a").on("tap", function(){
    switch($(this).attr("href")) {
  case "#woke":
            console.log("#woke");
   $.mobile.changePage("#woke");
   break;
        case "#network": 
            console.log("#network");
   $.mobile.changePage("#network");
   break;
    }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Organize.me</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 
 <body>     
  <div data-role="page" id="woke">
   <!--Navigation panel with links-->
   <div data-role="panel" data-dismissible="true" data-swipe-close="true" data-display="overlay" data-fixed-position="true" id="menu">
    <div data-role="header">      
      <h1>Menu</h1> 
      <a href="#network" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Back</a>
    </div>    
    <nav><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> 
     <a href="#woke" class="nav-woke"><li class="buttons">Get Woke</li></a>
     <a href="#network"><li class="buttons">My Network</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Find Orgs</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Events</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Voting</li></a>   
    </ul></nav>
   </div>
   
   <!--Header-->
   <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#menu" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left">Menu</a>
    <h1>Get Woke</h1>
   </div>
   
   <!--Content-->
   <div data-role="content"></div>
   
   <!--Footer-->
   <div data-role="footer">&copy;Scripts of Steele</footer>
  </div>
  
  <div data-role="page" id="network">
   <!--Navigation panel with links-->
   <div data-role="panel" data-dismissible="true" data-swipe-close="true" data-display="overlay" data-fixed-position="true" id="menu">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a href="#network" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Back</a>
      <h1>Menu</h1>    
    </div>    
    <nav><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> 
     <a href="#woke" data-rel="open"><li class="buttons">Get Woke</li></a>
     <a href="#network" data-rel="open"><li class="buttons">My Network</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Find Orgs</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Events</li></a>
     <a href="#"><li class="buttons">Voting</li></a>   
    </ul></nav>
   </div>
   
   <!--Header-->
   <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#menu" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left">Menu</a>
    <h1>My Networks</h1>
   </div>
   
   <!--Content-->
   <div data-role="content"></div>
   
   <!--Footer-->
   <div data-role="footer">&copy;Scripts of Steele</footer>
  </div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't change anything for me

Comment: @AndrewS. what are you trying to change? do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: I'm only trying to change the current page that's being displayed. In the developer mode console on chrome I'm not getting any errors